# Merge three collections in Laravel by key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have 3 collections:

```
+----------------+  +----------------+  +----------------+ 
|     Posts      |  |   PostImages   |  |   PostFiles    |
+----------------+  +----------------+  +----------------+
|   id           |  |   id           |  |   id           |
|   title        |  |   post_id      |  |   post_id      |
|   description  |  |   patch        |  |   patch        |
|   user_id      |  +----------------+  |   description  |
+----------------+                      +----------------+
```

Controllers:

```
$posts = User::find($userdata->id)->posts;

$postids = Post::where('user_id', $userdata->id)->pluck('id')->toArray();

$images = PostImage::wherein('post_id ', $postids )->get()->All();

$files = Docs::wherein('post_id', $postids )->get()->All();
```

Is it possible to combine these three collections without using the loop, to get this structure:

```
[post1] => [
    title => title,
    content => content,
    images => collection [
                        image1 => patch,
                        image2 => patch,
                        image3 => patch,
                        ],
    Files => [
        [0] => [
            file1 => patch,
            description1 => description
        ],
        [1] => [
            file2 => patch,
            description2 => description
        ]
    ]
],
[post2] => [
    title => title,
    content => content,
    images => collection [
                        image1 => patch,
                        image2 => patch,
                        image3 => patch,
                        ],
    Files => [
        [0] => [
            file1 => patch,
            description1 => description
        ],
        [1] => [
            file2 => patch,
            description2 => description
        ]
    ]
],
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe all of these are related. Possible to fetch everything in one query using joins ? That way you will avoid loops and also save no. of queries. Refer: [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) or [Query Builder Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Laravel's 'WITH' is just what you need.

Example:

In you post model add these functions.

```
public function images()
{
  return $this->hasMany(YouImageModel::class, 'post_id');
}

public function files()
{
 return $this->hasMany(YourFileModel::class, 'post_id');
}
```

So when getting post you can eager load the images.

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $userdata->id)->with(['images', 'files])->posts;
```

Here is the [doc link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)